# How to enable Virtualisation on Windows 8?

Tags: docker

I am trying to figure out how to enable Virtualisation on my Windows 8 so that I can install docker. I have as shown below on the image

[image]

I can not find ways to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

From http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/hyper-v-run-virtual-machines:

> 1. In Control Panel, tap or click Programs, and then tap or click Programs and Features.
> 2. Tap or click Turn Windows Features on or off.
> 3. Select Hyper‑V, tap or click OK, and then tap or click Close.
> 4. Shut down your PC, and then restart it.
>
> Depending on your manufacturer, you might have to pause a few seconds
>   with the PC off before restarting for the required changes to take
>   effect. If you're using a laptop, you might have to remove the battery
>   before restarting.

if not yet enabled in bios: http://www.sysprobs.com/disable-enable-virtualization-technology-bios

Comment: I had no Hyper-V in the Windows Features on or off. I tried that process and got stuck on step 3 since I do not have it!

Comment: It must be enabled in bios/uefi first, to enable the option for OS.
And (if enabled) disable fast boot. http://superuser.com/questions/530379/hyper-v-wont-enable-in-windows-8-pro-virtualization-support-is-disabled-in-th#answer-531560